# Connecting a remote phpmyadmin server with c# application

Tags: c#, mysql, string, connection

```
public class DBconnect
{
    public DBconnect()
    {
        private static string connectString = "datasource = 192.168.xx.xxx:6060/localhost;username = root;password = ;database = testlogin";

        public MySqlConnection dbConnect = new MySqlConnection(connectString);

        try
        {
            dbConnect.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to write this connection string. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private static string connectString = "server =192.168.xx.xxx;user id  = root;password = ;database = testlogin";
```

Comment: I have my database in diffferent pc. So by localhost i can only access my db

Comment: do you have any question?

Comment: where do I specify my port number :6060 ?